# add properties to php pbject

Tags: php, loops

I have this object that represents colors with counts
I am trying to add property of color code to the object from another array

printing object `$oColors` :

```
  stdClass Object
    (
        [black] => 2207
        [blue] => 783
        [red] => 672
        [white] => 555
        [green] => 463
    )
```

and  am trying to loop through them and map them with another array of objects like below :

```
foreach ($oColors as $color => $count) {
    if (array_key_exists($color, $oColorsMapper)) {
        $oColors->$color['code']= $oColorsMapper->$color->code;
    }
}
```

but printing the result is showing the object is still the same

what am I doing wrong thanks

Comment: you can use `array_merge`. Can you just show the sample how you want the result array to be

Comment: Is the `foreach` inside a function?

Comment: Yep, seems your foreach inside a function and you forget to pass variable with &

Comment: yes it is inside a function , where to use & ? @VictorPerov

Comment: @sisimh add the whole code because it's very unclear how you are using those variables

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the keys are not arrays. They are strings. So the solution would be something like:

```
foreach ($oColors as $color => $count) {
    if (array_key_exists($color, $oColorsMapper)) {
        $oColors->$color = array(
             'count' => $count,
             'code'  => $oColorsMapper->$color->code
        );
    }
}
```

As a simple example:

```
$arr = (object) array('test' => 43, 'test1' => 435);

function test($obj) {
    foreach ($obj as $key => $val) {
        $obj->$key = array($val);
    }
}

test($arr);

var_dump($arr);
```

will output:

```
object(stdClass)#1 (2) {
  ["test"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    int(43)
  }
  ["test1"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    int(435)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@sisimh
Your problem is passing variable into function without reference.
By default, function arguments are passed by value (so that if the value of the argument within the function is changed, it does not get changed outside of the function). To allow a function to modify its arguments, they must be passed by reference. More info u can get [here](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php)

So, if you have function:

```
function changeColors ($oColors) {
    ...
}
```

You should change $oColors to &$oColors, like this:

```
function changeColors (&$oColors) {
```

Next point is that $color from your example with foreach section is not an array. It'a a key value (in most cases it has a string type). Perhabs, you made mistake and ['code'] should be absent.

Another point of my attention is `array_key_exists`. In most cases better to use `isset` instead of `array_key_exists`. It's a more faster way.

For example:

```
function changeColors (&$oColors) {
    ...
    foreach ($oColors as $color => $count) {
        if (isset($oColorsMapper->$color)) {
            $oColors->$color = $oColorsMapper->$color->code;
        }
    }
    ...
}
```